# Time taken for insertion of bulk data in Sqlite - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have to insert a bulk of records in datbase using sqlite for windows phone.I have a table where I have to insert 60,000+ records.I am inserting the records in the following manner:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)   
{ 
    dbase.Insert(new Vehicles()
    {
        model = list[j].getModel(),
        submodel = list[j].getSubmodel(),
        engine = list[j].getEngine()
    });
}
```

where `list.count = 66101`
It is taking a total time of 50 mins to insert this data.Kindly,help me out how I can reduce this time to least time taken for insertion.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. You are far more likely to get good answers if people don't have to take 15 minutes to decipher your code.

Comment: Do not make single line inserts. Use multiple threads. Realize that maybe SqlLite is a little too small here?

Comment: I have dealt with a situation like this where I was required to insert about 40,000 records in a DB on windows phone 7. The best option is to do it in background, after notifying the user that it is a one time, time consuming process (otherwise your app might not pass the certification for windows phone market). I was using the sterling DB which I found to be much effiecient and easy to use, you might want to give it a try. http://sterling.codeplex.com/